# One macro for multiple rows of list validations

Tags: excel, vba

I searched but couldn't find an answer to what I imagine to be an easy solution. I have multiple rows of list boxes (basically a yes/no questionnaire) and I would like a macro that changes other cells in the same row depending on what is selected from the list in column A. I assume it needs to be a change event and I can do what I want for a single row, but can't figure out how to apply it to the entire column. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(True, True) = "A2" Then
    Select Case Target
        Case "list option one"
            call Macro1
        Case "list option 2"
            'Call Macro2
        Case Else
            'Do nothing
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

obviously I don't want to hard code each row A3, A4, A5...

Comment: Assuming it's locked down then you could add an 'If' Statement to the other row instead of using a Macro then Excel will do the 'trigger' work for you.

Comment: Would it not be a good alternative to define functions for the values of the cells you are targetting with your macro's. These functions can operate in the same manner as normal Excel functions but, because they are written in VBA, can contain more specific functionailty. As the input parameter you can pass the value of the cell in column A.

Comment: @indofraiser do you mean by using excel functions? The problem with that is that some of the values would be free-text, and that would delete the function.

Comment: @Tom That would only work if their is a set number of rows in column A right? It is an always increasing list, not sure how that would work. Any ideas?

Comment: Of course it would mean copying the formulas to the added rows, but for that you could write a macro. Free text would of course remove the formula, but a macro going through the rows would likely also have some difficulty with these free text values. Anyway, it was just a suggestion that may work depending on the situation you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Target.Value = True Then 'If target = true (This can be what ever you want)
        Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = True 'Then put true on same row but column 2 e.g. B
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand what's going on here...if say I wanted to make the cell in column B say "N/A" if list option 1 is selected, where do I put this code?

Comment: Put this under the sheet.

    If Target.Value = True Then

Change the above "True" to the value you select from the dropdowns in column A

    Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = True

Change "True" to what you want in column B when the IF statement is true

Comment: or you could change If Target.Value = True Then to if Target.Value <> "" Then if you would like to have any value except blank come through

Comment: Just a side note: there is a similar event at workbook level which would cover the whole document, can be more hassle tho. Think its workbook_change in the thisowrkbook module. Glad its working